# ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'django.db.models.functions'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-filter

Well, I am trying to run my django project in new environment, I installed all of my requirements although every package is installed but it is still giving me below mentioned error. I am not sure but I am guessing it is due to version conflict of some modules.
[image: error thrown by compiler]

I looked for existing solutions or someone who faced similar situation but no success.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: In general, when a third-party module has an import error on another third-party module, that's an indication that one or both of those modules are out of date.  Have you upgraded to the latest versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **Random** method is located in **django/db/models/functions/math.py .** change your  import statement  to this  :

```
from django.db.models.functions.math import Random
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

If you're encountering this error in a 3rd-party package, either upgrade Django to 3.2 or later, or downgrade the 3rd-party package to a version that supports Django versions before 3.2.

**Longer answer**:

I encountered the same issue with the `mssql-django` package in the asker's screenshot, and I had a combination of `Django<3.2` and `mssql-django>=1.2` installed. Like me, you'll need to either upgrade `Django` to 3.2 or later, or downgrade `mssql-django` to 1.1 or lower.

Root cause is that [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/commit/1b30d21a4af45a28f83cc77ff799e5d17304ab31) (added in the `mssql-django` 1.2 release) was implemented without checking which Django versions it could work with. `Random` wasn't exported from `django.db.models.functions` until [this change](https://github.com/django/django/commit/06c5d3fafc6aeb96387148726713b611aeba7fa1), which was added in the Django 3.2 release.